# Installing nservicebus Servicecontrol in loadbalanced environment

Tags: nservicebus, nsb-servicecontrol

I am to install NServiceBus ServiceControl in a two machine setup (Load balanced by F5 box).
any idea if both instance are sharing same RavenDatabase location, will it work?

Answer (score 3):

ServiceControl uses an embedded RavenDB instance. This configuration does not support load balancing. It only supports high availability via clustering (active/passive).

See the following guidance on high availability:

http://docs.particular.net/servicecontrol/deploying-servicecontrol-in-a-cluster